# How to create a series of number based on two variables?

Tags: sas, numbers, series

Let's say I have this df

```
data df;
input Country $ Year;
datalines;
USA 2019
USA 2019
USA 2020
Canada 2019
Canada 2020
Canada 2020
;
run;
```

I know how to create a series of numbers based on one variable but how to make it based on two variables. I want the following output

```
Country   Year   series
-------   ----   ------
USA       2019   1
USA       2019   2
USA       2020   1
Canada    2019   1
Canada    2020   1
Canada    2020   2
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show your code for creating SERIES based on one variable (COUNTRY).  Sharing that will help people help you extend it to two variables.  Are you using a DATA step with BY group processing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's nearly the same way as you would with one variable. Specify both groups in your `by` statement.

```
data want;
    set df;
    by descending country year;

    if(first.year) then series = 0;

    series+1;
run;
```

```
Country Year    series
USA     2019    1
USA     2019    2
USA     2020    1
Canada  2019    1
Canada  2020    1
Canada  2020    2
```

In this code, saying `if(first.year)` implies that it is the first year in the group `(country year)`. Your `by` group can be thought of a hierarchy in this sense:

`by var1 var2 var3 var4 ... varn`

| first. | Group |
| --- | --- |
| first.var1 | var1 |
| first.var2 | var1 var2 |
| first.var3 | var1 var2 var3 |
| first.var4 | var1 var2 var3 var4 |
| ... | ... |

You can verify this by adding a binary variable showing the first values of each group. Think of it as a shortcut for `if(first.var1 AND first.var2)`. `first.var2` already implies this.

```
data want;
    set df;
    by descending country year;

    first_country      = (first.country);
    first_country_year = (first.year);
run;
```

```
Country Year    first_country   first_country_year
USA     2019    1               1
USA     2019    0               0
USA     2020    0               1
Canada  2019    1               1
Canada  2020    0               1
Canada  2020    0               0
```